# Cypher query to find paths through directed weighted graph to populate ordered list

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and am trying wrap my mind around the following problem in Cypher.

I am looking for a list of nodes, sorted by ascending visitation order, after a run of n path iterations, each of which adds nodes to the list. The visitation sort depends on depth and edge cost. Because the final list represents a sequence of nodes you could also look at it as a path of paths.

**Description**

- My graph has an initial starting node (START), is directional, of unknown size, and has weighted edges.
- A node can only be added to the list once, when it is first visited (e.g. when visiting a node, we compare to the final list and add if the node isn't on the list already).
- Every edge can only be traveled once.
- We can only visit the next adjacent, lowest-cost node.
- There are two underlying hierarchies: depth (the closer to START the better) and edge costs (the lower the cost incurred to reach the next adjacent node the better). Depth follows the alphabetical order in the example below. Cost properties are integers but are presented in the example as strings (e.g. "costs1" means edge cost = 1).
- Each path starts with the starting node of least depth that is "available" (= possessing untraveled outbound edges). In the example below all edges emanating from START will have been exhausted at some point. For the next run we'll continue with A as starting node.
- A path run is done when it cannot continue anymore (i.e. no available outbound edges to travel on)
- We're done when the list contains y nodes, which may or may not represent a traversal.

Any ideas on how to tackle this using Cypher queries?

---

**Example data:** http://console.neo4j.org/r/o92sjh

**This is what happens:**

1. We start at START and travel along the lowest-cost edge available to arrive at A. --> A gets the #1 spot the list and the costs1 edge in START-[:costs1]->a gets eliminated because we've just used it.
2. We’re on A. The lowest cost edge (costs1) circles back to START, which is a no-go, so we take this edge off the table as well and choose the next available lowest-cost edge (costs2), leading us to B. --> We output B to the list and eliminate the edge in a-[:costs2]->b.
3. We're now on B. The lowest cost edge (costs1) circles back to START, which is a no-go, so we eliminate that edge as well. The next lowest-cost edge (costs2) leads us to C. --> We output C to the list and eliminate the just traveled edge between B and C.
4. We're on C and continue from C over its lowest-cost relation on to G. --> We output G to the list and eliminate the edge in c-[:costs1]->g.
5. We're on G and move on to E via g-[:costs1]->e. --> E goes on the list and the just traveled edge is eliminated.
6. We're on E, which only has one relation with I. We incur the cost of 1 and travel on to I. --> I goes on the list and E's "costs1" edge gets eliminated.
7. We're on I, which has no outbound edges and thus no adjacent nodes. Our path run ends and we return to START iterating the whole process with the edges that remain.
8. We're on START. Its lowest available outbound edge is "cost3", leading us to C. --> C is already on the list, so we just eliminate the edge in START-[:costs3]->c and move on to the next available lowest-cost node, which is F. Note that now we've used up all edges emanating from START.
9. We're on F, which leads us to J (cost =1) --> J goes on the list, the edge gets eliminated.
10. We're on J, which leads us to L (cost = 1)--> L goes on the list, the edge gets eliminated.
11. We're on L, which leads us to N (cost = 1)--> N goes on the list, the edge gets eliminated.
12. We're on N, which is a dead end, meaning our second path run ends. Because we cannot start the next run from START (as it has no edges available anymore), we move on to next available node of least depth, i.e. A.
13. We're on A, which leads us to B (cost = 2) --> B is already on the list and we dump the edge.
14. We're on B, which leads us to D (cost = 3) --> D goes on the list, the edge gets eliminated.
15. Etc.

**Output / final list / "path of paths"** (hopefully I did this correctly):

```
A

B

C

G

E

I

F

J

L

N

D

M

O

H

K

P

Q

R
```

---

```
CREATE (  START { n:"Start" }),(a { n:"A" }),(b { n:"B" }),(c { n:"C" }),(d { n:"D" }),(e { n:"E" }),(f { n:"F" }),(g { n:"G" }),(h { n:"H" }),(i { n:"I" }),(j { n:"J" }),(k { n:"K" }),(l { n:"L" }),(m { n:"M" }),(n { n:"N" }),(o { n:"O" }),(p { n:"P" }),(q { n:"Q" }),(r { n:"R" }),

START-[:costs1]->a, START-[:costs2]->b, START-[:costs3]->c, 
a-[:costs1]->START, a-[:costs2]->b, a-[:costs3]->c, a-[:costs4]->d, a-[:costs5]->e, 
b-[:costs1]->START, b-[:costs2]->c, b-[:costs3]->d, b-[:costs4]->f, 
c-[:costs1]->g, c-[:costs2]->f, 
d-[:costs1]->g, d-[:costs2]->f, d-[:costs3]->h, 
e-[:costs1]->i, 
f-[:costs1]->j, 
g-[:costs1]->e, g-[:costs2]->j, g-[:costs3]->k, 
j-[:costs1]->l, j-[:costs2]->m, j-[:costs3]->n, 
l-[:costs1]->n, l-[:costs2]->f, 
m-[:costs1]->o, m-[:costs2]->p, m-[:costs3]->q,
q-[:costs1]->n, q-[:costs2]->r;
```

Comment: can you post example data and expected query results?

Comment: Weight on a node would be the same regardless of predecessor in the path, if you want relative weight use relationship property. Are you looking for the path with the smallest total weight, or the path where every step has the smallest weight? `(a)-[{w:1}]->(b)-[{w:9}]->(c) //(sum:10)` or `(a)-[{w:2}]->(b)-[{w:2}]->(c) //(sum:4)`?

Comment: FYI - I updated the description and included sample data and desired output. Thanks!

Comment: could you describe your use-case more in terms of what you expect as the outcome than the algorithm (which is pretty imperative). I think a java-extension might be much better suited than cypher, as your algorithm could be translated 1:1 into java code.

Comment: Hi Michael, the only reason why I looked to neo4j for this was concern about query complexity and computing power requirements when using relational dbs. Using a java extension would be fine. The end goal is to assign a node list like this to every node in the graph and extract various properties from those nodes.

Comment: Oh, and thanks so much for putting up a bounty for this!

Comment: This seems identical to the greedy heuristic for TSP of an incomplete graph.

Comment: If I remember correctly, TSP requires visiting every node exactly once, seeks to MIN overall path length, and returns to the starting node. Here, we visit every edge once, but nodes multiple times, overall path length is irrelevant, and we don't want to return to the starting node (in fact, the starting node shifts at some point)...

Comment: You are correct Pat, I meant to say "almost identical". There are only a few modifications that need to be made to the code, but since the algorithm is only a few lines anyway, it ends up being relatively large changes. That being said, my comment wasn't about what the greedy algorithm tries to do, but rather what it actually does, which is keep selecting the next smallest valid edge. Valid edge changing from an edge with an unvisited vertex to an unvisited edge. I ended deciding to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm being sought is a modification to the [nearest neighbor (greedy) heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) for TSP. The changes to the algorithm result in an algorithm that looks like this:

1. stand on the start vertex an arbitrary vertex as current vertex.
2. find out the shortest unvisited edge, E, connecting current vertex, terminate if no such edge.
3. set current vertex to V.
4. mark E as visited.
5. if the the number of visited edges has reached the limit, then terminate.
6. Go to step 2.

As with the original algorithm, the output is the visited vertices.

To handle the use case, allow for the algorithm to take in a set of already visited edges as an additional input. Rather than always starting with an empty set of visited edges. You then just call the function again but with the set of visited edges rather than an empty set until the starting vertex only leads to visited edges.

Comment: I'd love to see the concrete implementation.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not familiar with Cypher (and only barely so with SQL), and my attempts to workout the sytax hasn't done well. However, it seems like you'd have to create an empty set, start at a node, follow the shortest edge from that node, add that edge to the set and repeat until no edge can be followed. Combining REDUCE (try to follow each edge from a node), WHERE (actually only follow the shortest node), and a set (combined with WHERE to only follow an edge once) should be able to get it done if somewhat by brute force.

Comment: I thought about a bit more, a reduce probably isn't the best option. Seems like a nested foreach would be required instead as reduce may cause issues if implemented as a parallel method. The outer layer allows for the possibility that all edges could be added to the path by founding from 0 to the number of edges (should be a way to stop early). Inside the loop, finds the smallest edge that isn't in the set, adds it to the set of used edges and to the end of the path.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I'm new on the site, can't comment)
I was hired to find a solution to this particular query. I only learned of this question afterward. I am not going to post it at full here, but I am willing to discuss the solution and get feedback of anyone interested.

It turned out not being possible with cypher alone (well, I could not find out how myself). So  I wrote a java function with the Neo4j bindings to implement this.

The solution is single threaded, flat (no recursion), and very close to the description of @Nuclearman. It uses two data structures (ordered maps), one to remember visited edges, another to keep a list of "start" nodes (for when the path runs out):

1. Follow path of smallest costs (memorize visited edges, store nodes by depth/cost)
2. On end of path, pick a new start node (smallest depth first, then smallest cost)
3. Report any new node in the order they are accessed

The use of hash sets, coupled with the fact that edges are visited only once makes it fast and memory efficient.